# Как исправить PST-файл более 2ГБ?

Tags: windows, email, outlook

Теперь не могу открыть самостоятельно созданный *PST*,  который составляет более чем 2 ГБ. Я хотел бы переместить некоторые письма в другой *PST*. Как можно это исправить и открыть его снова. Спасибо.

Comment: Чем вы создавали этот файл?

Answer (score 1):

Если умеете программировать, то можете воспользоваться библиотекой [libpst](http://hg.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/) или аналогичной.

Если не умеете, можно попробовать утилиту для просмотра pst-файлов вроде [этой](http://www.nucleustechnologies.com/pst-viewer.html)